# How to trigger service function when other done?

Tags: angular

I have service with functions:

```
    saveObject_1(formData): Observable<Model_1> {
            return this.http.put('url_1', formData)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    saveObject_2(formData): Observable<Model_2> {
            return this.http.put('url_2', formData)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Model_1 has fk to Model_2. In component I can do it:

```
    this.myService.saveObject_1(form_1Data).subscribe(
        item => {
                    this.item = item;
                    this.myService.saveObject_2(form_2Data).subscribe(
                        item_2 => {
                            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                        },
                        error =>  {
                             this.errorMessage = <any>error
                        }
                    );
                },
        error =>  {
                    this.errorMessage = <any>error
                }
    );
```

but I have many dependencies like this and not all have to exist - I get a lot of "if's" .

How to trigger this.myService.saveObject_2 after properly saved this.myService.saveObject_1 without nesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` (or `mergeMap`) for this, which doesn't execute the second method, until the first one is "ready".

```
chainRequests(form_1Data, form_2Data) {
  this.myService.saveObject_1(form_1Data)
    .map(item => this.item = item)
    .flatMap(item => this.myService.saveObject_2(form_2Data))
    .subscribe(item2 => {
       this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });
}
```

`flatMap` would usually be used when second http request is dependent on the result of the first http-request, so above the `saveObject_2` method would be dependent on `item` to be able to perform request, therefore has to be chained. This is not the case here though, but I don't see why we couldn't use `flatMap` to chain http-requests in general :) As said [**here**](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs):

> The mergeMap operator helps us by subscribing and pulling the value out of the inner Observable and passing it back to the parent stream. This condenses our code quite a bit and removes the need of a nested subscription.

Finally a...

### **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8sc0mYVqpyWXSF2bH8be?p=preview)**